# Whats the difference between capturing packets with wifi card vs. setting up Port mirroring with IDS/IPS?

Tags: networking

Looking into setting up and IDS/IPS system to capture all the traffic over my network, but not quite sure how to go about it.  First off, what is the difference between capturing packets with a wifi card vs just setting up port mirroring.  This is what I want to do, I want to set up a device that will capture all the traffic going through my network.  However, I want this device to be as secure as possible.  It will be used for nothing else but capturing traffic.  I know port mirroring basically duplicates all traffic and sends it to the IPS/IDS device.  Does that mean it will be safe because traffic is not coming to and from the device but just too?  Lets say I decide to do this through port mirroring. This type of switch usually has GUI interface that can be connected over the internet.  Is there a way to lock that down so that it cannot be accessed from over the internet so to say or I guess as much as can be since it is the connection.  Thanks

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as the solution?  Let me know if I was unclear about anything.

Answer (score 0):

A packet capture taken on a computer connected to a switch (or over wifi) is only going to see packets that are broadcast (meaning requests like DHCP, where when a computer is first connected to a network and requests an address, it broadcasts to all available computers to see if it can find an DHCP server to give it an IP address) and Unidirectional traffic, or traffic speciifically between your computer while it attmepts to communicate with other machines on the network.   Now lets say you have two other computers on your network that are not capturing packets, one is a file server and one is a windows host.   Any communication that happens between those two hosts, you would never see if you were just capturing packets on a 3rd workstation.   The machine you are capturing packets with would not see this traffic because the conversation is happening between two specific hosts having a unicast conversation with eachother.

Now let's consider this same situation with an IDS with port mirroring configured on a managed switch to forward (or mirror) all of the traffic on all of the ports on a switch, to one specific switch port.   Since the data is mirrored, all of the conversations that are happening on the switch (unicast, multicast, broadcast) would be visible to your IDS solution.   The IDS would then perform some sort of analysis of your network traffic to determine if there was anything happening on your network that looked suspicious when compared to packet captures of various types of attacks or exploits.

One thing that you will need to have in order to setup port mirroring is a managed (meaning you can configure various aspects of how the switch operates) switch.   They usually cost a little more than your average dumb switch (dumb = cannot configure).   I know in regard to Cisco network switches, the port mirroring is usually called SPAN or RSPAN.   You would need to login to the CLI or Web Console for the switch, and then configure what ports and VLANs you want the port mirroring session to look at (you can specify a range of ports, port channels, VLANs, etc that you want to monitor) and then you tell the switch what switch port the traffic will be mirrored to.   Then you would connect an ethernet cable going from that port to your  IDS.

In regard to you being concerned about the network switch being accessible to others, as long as you are doing all of this on the LAN side of your network with a firewall between you and the outside world, you should be fine in that regard.  Obviously if someone with bad intentions got into the LAN side of your setup, this could go bad real fast, but that would apply to any breach of your network.   Unless you have some specific need to open a given port to the outside world, I would advise against any configuration to allow traffic over common ports like SSH (22/tcp),RDP (3389/tcp) HTTP (80/tcp) that originate from outside of your network (the internet) to the LAN side.  Doing so might seem like a good idea so you can access some critical infrastructure from anywhere, however any protocols commonly used for any sort of remote access are the same ones that people are going to be looking for when your external IP is scanned.

If you could give some details on what IDS solution you were thinking of using, or what type of network switch you were thinking of using, I could give some specific examples of how to accomplish what you are attempting to do.

Hopefully that answered your question.